# CSS Horizontal Alignment for divs

Tags: html, css

I am building a portfolio project and am having trouble aligning the div sections inside of main as intended. I would like the two text sections and the photo to all align horizontally. I also am trying to allow window scalability. I am new to web design so any help is greatly appreciated!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  background-image: url("./images/Pattern\ Background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

body::before {
  background-color: #8d9365F8;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Navigation */

nav {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(215, 213, 213);
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 gray;
}

nav a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: .5px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 1px gray;
  background: linear-gradient(#d9b29c, #b79785);
}

nav .button {
  display: inline;
  padding: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2% 2% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px -2% 2% rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset, 0 2% 2% rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -2px #c4a18d;
}

nav a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 2% 2% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px -2% 2% rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25) inset, 0 2% 2% rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset;
  background: #c0a08d;
}

nav .button:active {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2% 2% rgba(63, 63, 63, 0.1), 0px -2% 2% rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25) inset, 0 2% 2% rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset;
}

.banner {
  margin: 30px;
}


/* Content */

main {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

.skills li {
  text-align: left;
  left: 20%;
}

.photo img {
  margin: 0.2% 0 15% 0;
  height: 20%;
  width: auto;
}

.skills {
  float: left;
  color: whitesmoke;
  left: 3%;
}

.ocp {
  float: right;
  color: whitesmoke;
  right: 250px;
}

.side {
  background-color: #d9b29c;
  top: 15%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&family=Playfair+Display&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="button">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="button">
      <a href="#">Extra #1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="button">
      <a href="#">Extra #2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="button">
      <a href="#">About Me</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="banner">
  <h1>Merima Kulosman</h1>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <main>
    <div class="skills side">
      <h3>Skills:</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><span></span>Communication</li>
        <li><span></span>Problem Solving</li>
        <li><span></span>Writing</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="./style/images/Merima.png">
    </div>
    <div class="ocp side">
      <h3>Occupational Therapist</h3>
      <p>Welcome to my portfolio! As an experienced occupational therapist, I am committed to providing exceptional care that empowers individuals to achieve their goals. Through my personalized approach to therapy and expertise in various therapeutic techniques,
        I have been able to facilitate remarkable progress and life-changing outcomes for my clients. My dedication to excellence and client-centered philosophy make me a valuable asset to any organization seeking a compassionate and skilled occupational
        therapist. Please feel free to explore my portfolio to learn more about my expertise and how I can contribute to your team.</p>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aligning multiple items horizontally can be done easily using flexbox. [Here's](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) a good guide on how to use it.

Instead of trying to position all the content inside your main div manually, set the main's display to flex and let the flexbox do the work. See this [fiddle](https://codepen.io/zev18/pen/Jjazzxy?editors=1100). Note the changes to `.main` in the css:

```
main {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the following css in order to correct your issue
The CSS code below uses the flexbox properties to make the elements align horizontally. With the .flex-container we get a display property of flex with flex-direction set to row to display the child. Try it and check if it is corrected as you like

```
.flex-container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-evenly;
 align-items: center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 }

 .skills, .ocp, .photo {
 flex: 1 1 30%;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .flex-container {
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 }
 .skills, .ocp, .photo {
 flex: 1 1 auto;
 margin: 10px 0;
 padding: 10px;
 }
 }
```